# Why does have_comments return false but get_comments return array of commemts?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

enter code here

```
        <ol class="commentlist">
            fsdfds
            <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
        </ol>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
                'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                'type'      => 'list',
            ) ) );
            echo '</nav>';
        endif; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php _e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`get_comments()` doesn't get comments for the current post. So you're getting all comments regardless of post.

> The comment list can be for the blog as a whole or for an individual
>   post.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/